# Don't understand some functions of this code! removeAll

Tags: java, substring, removeall

Was given this by my lecturer, and some parts have confused me!

```
String removeAll(char c, String s) {

String to_return = "";

while(true) {
    if (s.equals(""))
        return to_return;

    // at this point s is not ""
    char c2 = s.charAt(0);
    if (c2 != c)
    {
        to_return += c2;
    }

    s = s.substring(1);
}

return to_return; // won't be reached

}

System.out.println(removeAll('l',"hello"));
```

1. I understand the code is to remove all the l from hello, I just don't understand how it does it!
2. `c2 = h` (first char of hello), if it is not equal to c `to_return += c2`? what does this mean, more importantly what is `+=`
3. The next step is very confusing for me too! `s = s.substring(1);` what does this do in this case I only understand substrings by (1,4) etc!

Thanks for helping

Comment: First, Your method does not get compiled since you have used while(true) and not used break anywhere in loop

Comment: @niiraj874u:  But...if the string is blank (and it will eventually get there), `return` will break the loop by exiting the method...

Comment: If your lecturer is going to do a session on how to choose identifier names, I would recommend skipping it.

Comment: If the efficiency of the functions doesn't improve during the next weeks of the lecture, it would be quite embarrassing for the lecturer. At least that function is one of the least effective ways of removing all occurences of a char from a String i can think of right now. This function can be implemented to run in O(n) time instead of O(n^2) after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> c2 = h (first char of hello), if it is not equal to c to_return += c2?
>   what does this mean, more importantly what is +=

Basically, if the current first `char` of the `String` is not equal to `c` (the character to remove), append it to the `to_return` value.  `+=` is a shorthand (in this `String` concatenation) for `to_return = to_return + c`

> The next step is very confusing for me too! s = s.substring(1); what
>   does this do in this case I only understand substrings by (1,4) etc!

`s.substring(1)` creates a new `String` of `s` starting from the second character, remember, `String` is, essentially, `0` indexed character array.  This is basically trimming of the first character of the `s` and assigning the result back to `s`.

So, for example, if `s` equals `Hello`, after `s = s.substring(1)`, `s` will be equal to `ello`

Think of it like `s.substring(1, s.length() - 1)`.  Take a look at [`String#substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) for more details

`return to_return; // won't be reached` is true, but

```
if (s.equals(""))
    return to_return;
```

Ensures that it will, eventually return a value.  Personally, I like to have a single entry and exit point for all my methods, as it reduces the complexity of probability that you'll miss something that will have you scratching your head, but that's just me...

The reason that the last `return` is required is because the compiler can't determine if the method could ever return or not.

Comment: @user3587796 Glad it helps.  IMHO the code you presented isn't a very good example ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
char c2 = s.charAt(0);
```

You are taking the first character of `s`. In this case, on the first iteration, it will be `h`.

```
if (c2 != c)
```

If `c2`(`h`) is not equal to `c`(`l`), then

```
to_return += c2;
```

this is called shorthand notation. You can think of that as

```
to_return = to_return + c2;
```

So, it concatenates `c2` to `to_return` and assigns the result to `to_return`. So, if initially `to_return` was `""`, after this statement it would have become `h`.

Now that we have considered the first character, we want to eliminate from the further consideration. So,

```
s = s.substring(1);
```

This creates a substring, starting from index `1` till the end of the string. So, we excluded the first character. On the next iteration, `s.charAt(0)` would be `e`, since `h` is not there in variable `s` anymore.

Apart from that, you could have written the same function, like this

```
String removeAll(char c, String s) {
    String to_return = "", char c2;

    while (s.equals("") == false) {
        c2 = s.charAt(0);
        if (c2 != c) {
            to_return += c2;
        }
        s = s.substring(1);
    }

    return to_return;
}

System.out.println(removeAll('l', "hello"));
```

Comment: `while (!s.isEmpty()) {` or `while (s.length() != 0) {` might be better and easier to read - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Indeed, but OP might be wondering if we change too much of the original code I believe.

Answer (score -1):

```
   static String removeAll(char c, String s) {

        String to_return = "";

        while(true) {
            if (s.equals(""))
                break;


            char c2 = s.charAt(0); //take first character of string 
            if (c2 != c) //check if char is diffrent, append it to result string else skip that same char using substring(1)
            {
                to_return += c2;
            }

            s = s.substring(1); //skip char if it is found to remove it from final result string. again in next while loop 
                                //do the same process..fetch first chr and compare with our supplied char
        }

        return to_return; // won't be reached

        }
```

I also added break insted of return as you will get compilation error due to while(true)

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for and there are at least 4 better ways that I can think of to achieve this (ps- Not the downvoter)

Comment: Can anybody tell me what is the reason for down vote? If it answer does not tell the correct way, you can write comment and @MadProgrammer, I have not changed much code I have added my comments in it to describe what code does.

Comment: Like I said, the OP wasn't looking for corrections to the code, but answers to points 2 and 3 which they didn't understand about the code.

Comment: I have already described how code works.. please see my comments in code